# How to check is the @2x Image is exits

Tags: iphone, objective-c

there are some images have the @2x version in my project but some image is very small so, I dont need to make the @2x version of them.

My Question is: I need to know which version is loaded (regular version or @2x version or ~ipad version), How to check is the @2x version is exist ?

Thanks for reading my question ^^!

Comment: You want to know which image is used or you want to know image is exist or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"0"ofType:@"png"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSLog(@"file exixts ");
    } 
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"file not exixits");

    }
```

BUT remember it follow the alphabet case of the name provided for file .

Comment: Thank you ! This is what I will do: split the file name in two 2 string : FileName & Extent then check the @2x version by your code.

Answer (score 3):

You can check it by  metod fileExistsAtPath: of NSFileManager

Answer (score 2):

To check if it *exists* (which is different from *loaded*), you could do a nil-check:

```
UIImage *twoXImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeImageName@2x.png"];
if (!twoXImage)
    // Image does not exist
```

And if it does exist, you don't have to look through the file system again to grab that—just use the now-existing image. Much more efficient.

Comment: thanks but I think your code could be slow b/c we need CPU to load the image tghen check if it's null or not